# 1997 gmc jimmy Car cranks but wont start

Tags: gmc, cranks-wont-run, jimmy

So we have a 1997 jimmy GMC that has been running very well for quite a while. One day suddenly the car would not start. We had a couple of friends look at it and they said it might be the fuel pump or battery. We had replaced both of them and it started up just fine. it worked just fine for a few days then it stopped working with the same exact problem. We have been trying to fix it multiple times. We know that the pump runs just fine and we have been struggling to get it back on. If anyone has any tips that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you put a fuel pressure gauge on the rail to ensure the fuel pump is putting out the right pressure? You sure there's spark? Have you checked the fuse/relay to the injectors to ensure there's no issues?

Comment: This model is notorious for the fuel pump relay to fail, it is an integral (soldered) part of the fuse box and cannot be repaired easily.